# Apply a custom pipe to Material Table data

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In Angular 5, I am familiar with filters applied to *ngFor, using custom pipes, like this:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="hide_completed">Hide completed?</mat-slide-toggle>

<mat-card *ngFor='let task of tasks | callback:hideCompleted:hide_completed'>
...
</mat-card>
```

where *callback* is my generic pipe, *hideCompleted* the function declared in my component and *hide_completed* the variable I use to control the filter.

```
hideCompleted(task: Task) {
  return !task.completed
}
```

What I want now is to apply same filter to some data presented in a Material Table like below:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
...
</mat-table>
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6178) discussion is useful and helped me resolve it by replacing MatTableDataSource with a custom DatSource

Answer (score 1):

You will have to filter your datasource.

`this.datasource = this.datasource.filter(item => (your logic here));`

Makesure you have another copy of the original datasource, because `filter` will mutate the datasource.

Comment: Thanks! Just a correction for future reference, dataSource.data is to be filtered.